# blank space after "%c" in scanf format string ignores last character

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    while (scanf(" %c ", &c) != EOF)
        printf("you typed: %c \n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

I can just put blank space before `%c` like `" %c"` to let `scanf` read  a single character and skip any white spaces, but if I put another blank space after `%c` there comes problems:

```
a s d f
you typed: a
you typed: s
you typed: d
1 2 3
you typed: f
you typed: 1
you typed: 2
```

so why does it leave last character in input stream? Even though I actually typed `"a s d f "` with tailing space.

In fact `scanf` leaves `"f \n"` unread, right?

btw in the case of `" %c"` there's no problem as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [draft of the C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html):

> [**7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function**](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6)
>
> [...]
>
> [5.](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p5)  A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails.

This means that a whitespace character in the format string of `*scanf` will read and discard all whitespace characters **until a non-whitespace character is encountered**.

So, even if you input `"a s d f "`, your `scanf`, after consuming the `f`, would read and discard the final space *and* would wait for further input as it hasn't encountered a non-whitespace character yet.

You can close the stream by sending in an `EOF` signal so that the `scanf` will stop scanning and return `EOF`. Or you could remove that space and revert it to `" %c"` which you originally had.